# Arithmetic and geometric progression - 3 terms

Tags: number-theory

Find $3$ numbers $x, y, z$ which are consecutive terms of a geometric series, if $xy$, $yz$, $zx$ and $xyz$ are consecutive terms of an arithmetic series.

OK $y=xa$ and $z=xa^2$.
Also $yz=xy+b$
$zx=xy+2b$ and
$xyz=xy+3b$
So by substituting we get: $a=0$ (rejected) and $a=-\frac 1 2 $. But then how do I get $b$?

Comment: @Stefan: Thanks for the edit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x = a$, $y = ar$ and $z = ar^2$, $(a,r \ne 0)$, then

$xy = a^2r$, $yz = a^2r^3$, $zx = a^2 r^2$ and $xyz = a^3r^3$

Since $xy$, $yz$ and $zx$ are in AP.

$$yz = \dfrac{xy + zx}{2} \iff a^2r^3 = \dfrac{a^2r + a^2r^2}{2} \implies 2r^3 = r+ r^2 \implies r(2r^2 - r - 1) = 0$$

So $r = 1, -\dfrac12, 0$.

Also, $$zx=\dfrac{xyz + yz}{2}\iff a^2r^2 = \dfrac{a^3r^3 + a^2r^3}{2}  \implies 2 = ar + r \implies a = \dfrac{2 - r}{r}$$

$a = 1 (r = 1), -5(r = -1/2)$

Comment: So what are the 3 numbers in each case? I assume r can't be 1, or the 3 numbers would be equal?

Comment: Which three ? Why $r\ne 1$ ?

Comment: The numbers x, y and z.

Comment: @Alex.vollenga For $a = r = 1$, $x = y =  z = 1$. For $a = -5, r = -1/2$, $x = -5, y = 5/2, z = -5/4$ Is this what you are asking ?

Comment: @Alex.vollenga What wrong with three numbers being equal ? $1,1,1,1$ is both in AP and GP.

Comment: thanks a lot for the solution!!

Comment: @Alex.vollenga You're welcome.